# Using external NFS exports with kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

Is there any way to configure k8s so that pre defined nfs exports on some external nfs server , are only available for the pods that belong to a particular name space and other pods in other name spaces cannot mount it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to manage access to the NFS share in Kubernetes.

You can limit access by using NFS server with Kerberos.

You can find an example in the [NFSv4Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto) document.

Comment: Hi, do you mean if the shares are restricted to some username then we can configure k8s to to use that username for accessing the share?

Comment: Exactly. You can try to use tis client https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client for example.